# How do i Repopulate a TableView Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How i can repopulate again a Table View that is already populated? I do first show on my table view when it loads a couple results but when the user searches i need it to repopulate them again based on new results. Any guide?

Comment: [YourTableView reloadData]; ?

Comment: Thanks @remus let me recap, I make my call to the API and get the Response whiting the IBAction - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar { } and how do i pass the data again to the tableview? reloadData does just refresh the table?

Comment: If your datasource is updated on the IBAction, when you reload the table it will trigger a repopulation with the new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data Populates in Tableview will came from Dictionary or Array. So At the time when New data arrives you need to update that Dictionary or Array that you have used to Populate the tableview.

After that just you need to Reload the tableview like this:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

& its done.

Comment: I Wil try and tell you the results thanks for your time